# SDWebImageManager load local image

Tags: xcode, sdwebimage

How to SDWebImageManager load **local** images?

```
- (id<SDWebImageOperation>)downloadWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                               options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
                              progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock
                             completed:(SDWebImageCompletedWithFinishedBlock)completedBlock;


url NSURL * @"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/9BEC6D75-D655-4FC0-814C-ADC084270B27/Documents/Issues/de.20140808.SV.AA/full/articles/img/var/mobile/Applications/9BEC6D75-D655-4FC0-814C-ADC084270B27/Documents/Issues/de.20140808.SV.AA/full/articles/img/20140808001028882_2879337411704403.jpg"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use use UIImage object directly, SDWebImage designed to asynchronously download image of the web and not locally..

Comment: need use SDWebImageManager =)

Answer (score 0):

You want `SDImageCache`

Usage:
`let image = SDImageCache.shared.imageFromCache(forKey: url)`

If needed you can specify memory or disk cache, but by default it tries the in-memory cache and falls back to disk.